# View Angular 1 directive dependency/hierarchy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a tool or some way to view the hierarchy use of directives in your html templates? Something like [react-component-hierarchy](https://github.com/bpxl-labs/react-component-hierarchy) but for angular.  Or maybe AngularJSGraph but showing directives pointing to other directives that use them

Comment: Have you tried angular batarang? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Comment: I did and it doesn't give me a what I'm asking for in my question